# Array Splitting Scenario

Tags: c#, arrays

so I'm currently trying to do this scenario: 
Given a non-empty array, return true if there is a place to split the array so that the sum of the numbers on one side is equal to the sum of the numbers on the other side.
Examples:

```
canBalance([1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) → true
canBalance([2, 1, 1, 2, 1]) → false
canBalance([10, 10]) → true
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Array_Split
{
    class Program
    {
        public static bool Balance(int[] data)
        {
            int lpoint = 0;
            int rpoint = data.Length - 1;
            int ltotal = data[lpoint];
            int rtotal = data[rpoint];

            while (lpoint < rpoint)
            {
                if (ltotal == rtotal)
                {
                    lpoint++;
                    rpoint--;
                    ltotal = ltotal + data[lpoint];
                    rtotal = rtotal + data[rpoint];

                }
                else if (ltotal < rtotal)
                {
                    lpoint++;
                    ltotal = ltotal + data[lpoint];
                }
                else
                {
                    rpoint--;
                    rtotal = rtotal + data[rpoint];
                }

            }
            if (ltotal == rtotal)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] data2 = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 }; // T
            int[] data3 = new int[] { 2, 1, 1, 2, 1 }; // F
            int[] data4 = new int[] { 10, 10 }; // T

            Console.WriteLine(Balance(data2));
            Console.WriteLine(Balance(data3));
            Console.WriteLine(Balance(data4));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result should be true, false, true. However, it gives out false, true, true

Comment: Next step, debug your code. Use break points and step through it line by line to see why it returns unexpected results. You can use watches, quick watches, locales, etc. in Visual Studio to see the values of the variables/fields/properties as you are debugging.

Comment: Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the two values are equal, don't change both `lpoint` and `rpoint`. Consider what happens in `{1,2,1}` - they would both try to "claim" the value 2 at index 1, and you would incorrectly return true for that array. So instead, just change `lpoint`(*or* `rpoint`--just not both):

```
if (ltotal == rtotal)
{
    lpoint++;
    ltotal = ltotal + data[lpoint];    
}
else if ...
```

Because you're doing the same as when`ltotal < rtotal`, you can combine it with that block by checking `ltotal <= rtotal`:

```
if (ltotal <= rtotal)
{
    lpoint++;
    ltotal = ltotal + data[lpoint];
}
else
{
    rpoint--;
    rtotal = rtotal + data[rpoint];
}
```

Also, you shouldn't wait for `lpoint` to equal `rpoint` to end your loop - that means both sides need to claim some center index/value, which is against the rules. Instead, stop your loop when the points are adjacent:

```
while (lpoint + 1 < rpoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave this a shot just for fun.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace SO_58400592_array_split {
    class Program {
        private static List<int[]> _testCases = new List<int[]>() {
            {new int[] {1,1,1,2,1}},
            {new int[] {2,1,1,2,1}},
            {new int[] {10,10}}
        };

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            for (int index = 0; index < _testCases.Count; index++) {
                Console.WriteLine(CanSplitArray(_testCases[index]));
            }
        }



        static bool CanSplitArray(int[] model) {
            //  special case of 2 elements
            if(2 == model.Length) {
                return model[0] == model[1];
            }

            // sum the model
            int sum = model.Sum();

            //  caculate the value from each end
            int leftSum = 0;
            int rightSum = sum;
            //  start at the first index and end at the penultimate index.
            for (int index = 1; index < model.Length - 1; index++) {
                leftSum += model[index - 1];
                rightSum -= model[index - 1];
                if (leftSum == rightSum) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }   //  CanSplitArray()

    }   //  Program
}       //  ns
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution: But could offer some benefits:

```
    var sum = balance.ToList().Sum();
    if (sum % 2 == 0)
    {
        var left = 0;
        for (int i = 0; left < sum / 2; i++)
        {
            left+=balance[i];   
        }           
        return (left - (sum - left) == 0);
    }
    return false;
```

Since in order for a list to be even, it must also have a modulus result of 0, you can save time by skipping those that are obviously not equal on each side.

```
Sum(5,4,9) % 2 = 0
Sum(5,5,9) % 2 = 1
```

etc.

And then the code is different, but the algorithm is similar to make certain the left and right match.